# CPU usage: AJAX and Heartbeat API on admin pages

Tags: ajax, dashboard, memory, autosave, heartbeat-api

My (shared) web host recently sent me this:

> "Our server monitoring systems keep indicating high server load persistently maintained by your website (...). Most of the hits are to the `/www/www/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` script. We would advise the following:
>
> Do not stay logged into the WordPress dashboard through the day. Once you finish your work, you should log out. If you stay logged in and keep the browser window open, WordPress will keep generating hits to `admin-ajax.php`. ..."

When I asked them about this script, they replied:

> "WordPress calls this script to auto save your posts, and some other features of the dashboard. Any stats collection plugins can also contribute to the CPU usage of the script."

What do you think? Is this likely stats collection? Or why is it consuming so much memory? I've had other WP installs, including on this host, where I stayed logged in throughout the day. It's not like I have the dashboard or even my browser open all the time, either!

Comment: It seems this might be relevant, I just noticed: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/wordpress/heartbeat-ajax-php-usage

Comment: I wonder why the auto log out doesn't trigger. Or if the Heartbeat API keeps sending requests when the users gets logged out (as the log out is an AJAX action and no page reload happens).

Comment: guess it is time for you to start looking for better hosting. If 4 requests a minute are bringing them down what will happen when you will have actual traffic? But seriously you don't give enough details to be able to be of much help. That url serves all wordpress AJAX requests you might have other ajax based processes going on which are the rel reason for the load

Comment: Yeah, I wish I had more detail myself. I might just restrict the Heartbeat script to certain pages, as the link I found instructs. Switching hosts has occurred to me, but I'll wait to see if that headache is necessary. Thanks for the input!